# Reading in a file - Warning Message

Tags: r, warnings, read.table

I have a file that has 22268 rows BY 2521 columns. When I try to read in the file using this line of code:

```
file <- read.table(textfile, skip=2, header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE, blank.lines.skip=FALSE)
```

But I only get 13024 rows BY 2521 columns read in and the following error:

> Warning message: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns

I also used this command to see what rows had an incorrect number of columns:

```
x <-count.fields(textfile, sep="\t", skip=2)
incorrect <- which(x != 2521)
```

and got back a list of about 20 rows that were incorrect.

Is there a way to fill these rows with NA values?

I thought that is what the "fill" parameter does in the read.table function, but it doesn't appear so.

OR

Is there a way to ignore these rows that are identified in the "incorrect" variable?

Comment: check for spurious quotation marks and comment characters ...

Comment: There is no need for `R` in the title as the `r` `tag` makes that obvious.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid reading in the rows that are listed in "incorrect"?

Comment: @Sheila, If the goal is to have a data frame with only the correct lines, you can still read-in the bad lines to a temporary variable and  then from the temporary variable read only the "correct" lines.

Comment: Hi All.  I was able to solve this problem. after obtaining the number of "incorrect" rows, I created a vector called "allRows" that ranged from 1 to 22268 (included header), and found the rows I wanted to read in, by removing any of the row indexes that were "incorrect".  Then I was able to use readTable (from the R.utils library) to read in the rows that I actually wanted. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `readLines()` to input the data, then find the offending rows.

```
    con <- file("path/to/file.csv", "rb")
    rawContent <- readLines(con) # empty
    close(con)  # close the connection to the file, to keep things tidy
```

then take a look at `rawContent`

To find the rows with an incorrect number of columns, for example:

```
    expectedColumns <- 2521
    delim <- "\t"

    indxToOffenders <-
    sapply(rawContent, function(x)   # for each line in rawContent
        length(gregexpr(delim, x)[[1]]) != expectedColumns   # count the number of delims and compare that number to expectedColumns
    )
```

Then to read in your data:

```
  myDataFrame <- read.csv(rawContent[-indxToOffenders], header=??, sep=delim)
```

Comment: Hi @Ricardo - Is there a specific library you are suggesting to use?  In your example above you typed "library" then "expectedColumns <- 2521" etc...

Comment: Hi @Sheila, I was originally going to recommend using `stringr` in lieu of regex, but there was no need.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, and just to be clear, there should also be an assignment to indxToOffenders  correct?  So we see " indxToOffenders <- sapply...."?

Comment: Hi @Ricardo.  In my code above, the variable "incorrect", has the index of the rows that do not have all 2521 rows.  Is there a way to avoid reading in these rows?

Comment: Yep, you can use the argument n in readLines to only read in a few at a time. Can I ask why not just read them, but then not add them to your data frame?

Comment: Note the last line in this answer had `rawContent[-indxToOffenders]`, meaning that the bad rows will be excluded. (You can substitute `Incorrect` for `indxToOffenders` if you'd like)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20595/discussion-between-sheila-and-ricardo-saporta)